# How do i join all events related to a single identifier in KQL?

Tags: azure, kql, windows-defender, microsoft365-defender

A single alert in 365Defender often contains several events categorized by EntityType. I'm trying to collect all data related to a unique AlertID into a single line so it can all be correlated towards other tables (Device*Events). I've tried doing this through bag_pack > summarize make_set ()by AlertID, but I end up with the data double packed which means it's difficult to work with and if I do unpack it I've lost the ability to work with a single line.

Is there a proper way to do aggregate the data by a unique key in a single line, or am i SOL?

```
AlertEvidence
| where DetectionSource contains "Office"
| where AttackTechniques contains "phish"
//Collects data
| extend _mail=bag_pack("Title",Title ,"Timestamp",Timestamp, "AccountName",AccountName, "DeviceName",DeviceName, "EmailSubject",EmailSubject, "NetworkMessageId",NetworkMessageId,"FileName",FileName, "FolderPath",FolderPath, "SHA1",SHA1, "RemoteUrl",RemoteUrl)
//Sorts data per AlertID
| summarize make_set(_mail) by AlertId
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to join all events related to a single identifier in KQL:

To achieve your requirement, use `Make_list` instead of using `make_set` function to create a list of records for each `AlertID`.

Your code looks like below after modifications.

```bash
AlertEvidence 
| where DetectionSource contains  "Office" 
| where AttackTechniques contains  "phish"  
| extend _mail=pack("Title",Title ,"Timestamp",Timestamp, "AccountName",AccountName, "DeviceName",DeviceName, "EmailSubject",EmailSubject, "NetworkMessageId",NetworkMessageId,"FileName",FileName, "FolderPath",FolderPath, "SHA1",SHA1, "RemoteUrl",RemoteUrl) 
| summarize make_list(_mail) by AlertId
```

I ran a sample query log using the `make_list` function to put it in an understandable way, and it worked as explained.

***Output:***

[image]

Refer [article](https://arcanecode.com/2022/11/14/fun-with-kql-make_set-and-make_list/) by @Arcane Code for more information regarding `make_list` & `make_set`.